# How can I to specify the height where a color gradient starts using linear-gradient

Tags: html, css

How can I specify where color gradient starts in a div.

I have the below gradient:

```
style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white,#B8DBFF)
```

I would like the div to be purely white from top to around 200px down then have the gradient starts at that point.

Comment: [ColorZilla's css gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) may be some use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 200px,#b8dbff 100%);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CEFkZ/

(I used [this gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,ffffff+50,b8dbff+100;Custom))

Answer (score 0):

You can use degree to define the starting point.

Refer this to learn more about CSS3:

http://www.css3files.com/gradient/